# What is the proper way of restarting QApplication?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I'm Working with PySide, and seeking a way to restart my Qt app. Does this depends on python, or it has to be controlled by Qt?

BY ROSTYSLAV'S SUGGESTION BELLOW :

```
class MyAppMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        self.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT = -15123123
        exit_code = self.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT

    def slotReboot(self):

        print "Performing application reboot.."
        qApp.exit( self.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT )

def main():
    currentExitCode = 0
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyAppMainWindow()

    while currentExitCode == ex.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT :
        currentExitCode = app.exec_()

        return currentExitCode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Obviously I didn't fully understand. Pleas help.

Answer (score 4):

There's a nice way presented by Qt [Wiki](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ApplicationRestart) on how to make your application restartable.
The approach is based on recreation of `QApplication` instance and not killing current process.

It can be easily adopted to PySide like the next snippet shows:

```
EXIT_CODE_REBOOT = -15123123 # you can use any unique value here
exit_code = EXIT_CODE_REBOOT # Just for making cycle run for the first time

while exit_code == EXIT_CODE_REBOOT:
    exit_code = 0                       # error code - no errors happened
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ...
    exit_code = app.exec()
```

You just need to setup proper exit code through the API presenteed by `QApplication` before finishing your app. The you can hook up new configuration or whatever you need when new application instance is created.

Comment: I edited question with suggested code. Please can you look at it.

Comment: @Alex, You make 'return currentExitCode', obviously, doesnt matter what was the exit code your application will leave while loop after the first iteration (event worse, it'll finish `main` function). Move out 'return ...' line from while loop.

Answer (score 4):

The topic is quite old, but i see there is no proper solution provided. So here it is (based on what Rostyslav Dzinko suggested):

```
EXIT_CODE_REBOOT = -11231351

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):       
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
    def restart (self):            
        #DO stuff before restarting here            
        return QtCore.QCoreApplication.exit( EXIT_CODE_REBOOT )            

def start_app():

    exit_code = 0
    while True:
        try:
            app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        except RuntimeError:
            app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()            
        myap = MyApp()
        myap.show()            
        exit_code = app.exec_()            
        if exit_code != EXIT_CODE_REBOOT:
            break        
    return exit_code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_app()
```

Comment: The example script woud be better if you added a button to call the restart method. Also, you need to `import sys` somewhere.